# How do I stop Google Chrome from changing the current space in Spaces in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, osx-spaces

Whenever a website changes, finishes loading or re-loads; Google Chrome moves me to that Space. It drives me crazy. Is there any way of stopping that?

Comment: Stop Spaces from switching spaces due to an app coming to the foreground:
defaults write com.apple.Dock workspaces-auto-swoosh -bool NO && killall Dock

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've submitted this as a bug to Chrome, so far nobody denied that this is a problem, but nobody confirmed it either: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=46137

Comment: Please help this bug get fixed faster by voting for it.  Go to the bug page and click the star near the upper-left of the page.

Comment: The Chrome team can be quite pig-headed about admitting something is a bug, especially on macOS.  There was a long-standing problem with the delete key behaving as a back button on Mac Chrome, and they argued LITERALLY FOR YEARS! that despite many people unexpectedly losing all of their work in the current page it was not really a problem because of a UI precedent on Windows. ‍♂️

Answer (score 4):

To prevent OS X from ever automatically to switching spaces with open windows, you can enter the following into a Terminal window.

`defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-auto-swoosh -bool NO && killall Dock`

You'll still have to open a new window for the application though: Click the application in the dock, then press `cmd+n`.

Comment: this works as a workaround, but also removes useful functionality

Comment: I have done this and I still have Chrome moving me to different Desktops (although the circumstances are not exactly as described in this question)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. You could set Chrome to run in every space; that's what I do with my browser.

Comment: What do you mean by running in every space? I get all the same chrome windows replicated in all the spaces?

Comment: System Preferences -> Spaces lets you assign applications to specific spaces. If you select "every space" instead of a specific one, the windows of that application will follow you around as you move from space to space. It sounds like Chrome is stealing focus, which might still be disruptive if it's popping up from the background when you're in a different app, but I don't recall that behavior the last time I used Chrome. Make sure you're updated, and file a bug report if it persists!

Comment: Google Chrome doesn't show up at all in Spaces preferences on my OS X 10.6.5. There are a couple of "Unknown application" there I've tried to alter the space for, but to no avail. Chrome still only displays on the space that was active when it was first opened.

Comment: Did you click the plus button and add it to the list? I can do this and it works the way I described.